# Spring + Hibernate: Select from repository while it's updating an entry

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've just run into a problem, where I'm trying to select (repo.findById(id)) an object from the database using it's id, while it's being updated (Hibernate's onPreUpdate and onPostUpdate methods in PreUpdateEventListener and PostUpdateEventListener interfaces), but it's throwing a NullPointerException for me.

Perhaps it's easier if I explain it this way:

I have an object with status "PENDING", if it's being changed to "CONFIRMED", I want to check what the previous status was in the onPreUpdate method by doing this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent preUpdateEvent)
{
    final Object entity = preUpdateEvent.getEntity();

    if (entity instanceof Status)
    {
        Status status = (Status) entity;
        //Method below throws NullPointerException
        Status statusFromRepo = statusRepo.findByStatusId(status.getStatusId());
    }

    return false;
}
```

But since statusRepo is already updating this object in the database, am I not able to do anything to get the object BEFORE it's updated? PreUpdateEvent contains the already "updated" version which is going to be saved in the database.

Comment: The `PreUpdateEvent` has the `oldState` and `newState` already. Also I doubt the `NullPointerException` has anything to do with not being able to retrieve the entity, but rather our `statusRepo` being `null`. Generally a Hibernate listener isn't managed by Spring and thus won't autowire dependencies into it.

Comment: This helped a bit, I can now get the old state of the object, but is there any way to use repositories inside these event listener methods? I will need to use repositories to find, change, insert etc., but it's giving me null for the autowiring...

Comment: Don't sa that would lead to a loop. As you change you will get an update etc. The event contains both states. What is it you are trying to do/achieve with this listener?

Comment: I wanted to do an INSERT to another table if status gets changed, but I did this a simpler way (not sure if better), by creating services and methods that insert if status gets updated.